# Filtering section boxes won't remove blank spots

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTu93/17/)

I am having trouble filtering my section box for a project I am working on. Ideally the first section box would collapse to display only the filtered options, but instead just leaves the filtered options blank.
My html is :

```
    <select class="files">
        <option class="{{file | types:type}}"  ng-repeat="file in mdFiles" path="{{file.path}}" >{{file | types:type}}</option>
    </select>

    <select class="filters" ng-model="type" >
        <option ng-model="type" ng-repeat="options in filters" value="{{options.filter}}">{{options.filter}}</option>

    </select>
```

and my angular code:

```
app.filter('types', function () {
    return function (input, type) {
       console.log("i.t: " + input.type + ",t: " + type);
       if(input.type == type || type == 'all')
          return input.name;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/nXH5J/

Your filter

```
app.filter('types', function () {
    return function (files, type) {

        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
            if(file.type == type || type == 'all') {
             filtered.push(file);
           }
        });
        return filtered;
    }
    });
```

And select

```
<select class="files">
            <option ng-repeat="file in mdFiles | types:type"  path="{{file.path}}">{{file.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

You apply filtering on array and that filter is creating new array with filtered options.